# SingleChildScrollView not working, getting an bottom overflow error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have `SingleChildScrollView` within my widget tree, but still, I'm getting a `BOTTOM OVERFLOW BY 49 PIXELS` error. I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing.

[image]

Adding the exact error message I'm getting: It is pointing to the column wrapped within the `AutofillGroup` widget.

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 49 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///Users/sas/Projects/Development/App/Flutter/gesapp/lib/screens/sign_up.dart:105:28
: To inspect this widget in Flutter DevTools, visit: http://127.0.0.1:9100/#/inspector?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A64471%2FcGfO70O7M18%3D%2F&inspectorRef=inspector-31
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#a387c relayoutBoundary=up13 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=679.3)
...  size: Size(392.7, 679.3)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================
```

Listed below is the code which is causing the error.

```
class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/sign-up';

  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final nameNode = FocusNode();
  final emailNode = FocusNode();
  final passwordNode = FocusNode();

  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    nameController.dispose();
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    nameNode.dispose();
    emailNode.dispose();
    passwordNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appBar = AppBar(
      iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      leading: CustomBackButton(
        onPressed: () => print('Back Button Tapped'),
      ),
    );
    // ***** Start of checking for current Theme Mode *****
    var brightness = Theme.of(context).brightness;
    bool darkModeOn;
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      darkModeOn = true;
    } else {
      darkModeOn = false;
    }
    // ***** End of checking for current Theme Mode *****

    return KeyboardDismisser(
      gestures: [
        GestureType.onTap,
        GestureType.onVerticalDragDown,
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: isLoading ? null : appBar,
        body: isLoading
            ? Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SpinKitDoubleBounce(
                        color: kBrandColor,
                        size: Device.width! * 0.15,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.025),
                      Text(
                        'Loading...',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                child: Form(
                  key: formKey,
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: Device.height,
                    child: AutofillGroup(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Spacer(),
                          Container(
                            width: Device.width! * 0.9,
                            child: Text(
                              "Create Account",
                              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                                fontSize: 28,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.05),
                          TextInputField(
                            width: Device.width! * 0.90,
                            controller: nameController,
                            title: "Name",
                            icon: Icons.person_outline,
                            currentNodeName: nameNode,
                            nextNodeName: emailNode,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.03),
                          EmailInputField(
                            controller: emailController,
                            currentNodeName: emailNode,
                            nextNodeName: passwordNode,
                            width: Device.width! * 0.9,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.03),
                          Container(
                            width: Device.width! * 0.9,
                            child: PasswordInputField(
                              controller: passwordController,
                              inputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              currentNodeName: passwordNode,
                              width: Device.width! * 0.9,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.03),
                          CustomIconButton(
                            title: 'Sign up with Email',
                            buttonHeight: Device.height! * 0.07,
                            buttonWidth: Device.width! * 0.9,
                            buttonBackgroundColor: kBrandColor,
                            iconName: Icons.mail_outline,
                            iconColor: Colors.black,
                            textColor: kDarkThemePrimaryColor,
                            onPressed: signUp,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.025),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Already have an account? ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.color?.withOpacity(0.75),
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                ),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print("Sign In Button Tapped");
                                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(FadeAnimationPageRoute(SignIn()));
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  "Sign In",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.05),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Device.width! * 0.06),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
                                    builder: (context, currentTheme, child) => Container(
                                      child: Divider(
                                        height: 0.0,
                                        thickness: 1.0,
                                        color: currentTheme.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: Device.width! * 0.05),
                                Text(
                                  'OR',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: Device.width! * 0.05),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: Divider(
                                      height: 0.0,
                                      thickness: 1.0,
                                      color: darkModeOn ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.05),
                          darkModeOn
                              ? CustomImageButton(
                                  title: "Sign up with Google",
                                  buttonHeight: Device.height! * 0.07,
                                  buttonWidth: Device.width! * 0.9,
                                  buttonBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF4285F4),
                                  imageName: 'assets/images/google_logo.png',
                                  imageBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                                  textColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                                  onPressed: () => print("Google Sign Up Dark Mode Button Pressed"),
                                )
                              : CustomImageButton(
                                  title: "Sign up with Google",
                                  buttonHeight: Device.height! * 0.07,
                                  buttonWidth: Device.width! * 0.9,
                                  buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  imageName: 'assets/images/google_logo.png',
                                  imageBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  textColor: Color(0xFF000000),
                                  onPressed: () => print("Google Sign Up Light Mode Button Pressed"),
                                ),
                          SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.03),
                          darkModeOn
                              ? CustomImageButton(
                                  title: "Sign up with Apple",
                                  buttonHeight: Device.height! * 0.07,
                                  buttonWidth: Device.width! * 0.9,
                                  buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  imageName: 'assets/images/apple_logo_black.png',
                                  imageBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  textColor: Colors.black,
                                  onPressed: () => print("Apple Sign Up Dark Mode Button Pressed"),
                                )
                              : CustomImageButton(
                                  title: "Sign up with Apple",
                                  buttonHeight: Device.height! * 0.07,
                                  buttonWidth: Device.width! * 0.9,
                                  buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                  imageName: 'assets/images/apple_logo_white.png',
                                  imageBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  onPressed: () => print("Apple Sign Up Light Mode Button Pressed"),
                                ),
                          SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.02),
                          Spacer(),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: Device.height! * 0.03),
                            width: Device.width! * 0.9,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'By using our app you agree to it\'s',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.color?.withOpacity(0.75),
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: Device.height! * 0.0075),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print("Terms of Use Button Tapped");
                                        Navigator.of(context).push(FadeAnimationPageRoute(
                                          UserPreferences(),
                                          animationDuration: 1000,
                                          animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                                        ));
                                      },
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Terms of Use',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: Device.width! * 0.01),
                                    Text(
                                      'and',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.color?.withOpacity(0.75),
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: Device.width! * 0.01),
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print("Privacy Policy Button Tapped");
                                      },
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Privacy Policy',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          // color: Colors.black54,
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void signUp() {
    final form = formKey.currentState!;
    if (form.validate()) {
      TextInput.finishAutofillContext();
      final name = nameController.text.trim();
      final email = emailController.text.trim();
      final password = passwordController.text.trim();
      print("Name: $name");
      print("Email Address: $email");
      print("Password: $password");
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution is to wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` with `Container` that has a preferred size, for example:

```
Container(width: 400, height: 400, child: SingleChildScrollView(//your code))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try to add a height to all of your containers

Comment: But I don't know the height of all the containers. I don't want to constraint them to to a specific height. I want them to dynamically get resized.

Comment: I have posted the error message as well now. If at all that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The `SingleChildScrollView` is fine, but your `Column` Widgets are overflowing the Container's `height`, try removing the `Container` above `Column` or changing it's `height`

Comment: I removed the `Container`  which is wrapped within the `Form`, it didn't work out. Got plenty of errors and everything got disappeared in the widget tree.

Comment: Yes, removing was not a good idea, but what about changing it's height?

Comment: Already I have assigned its height to the device height. But still not working.